# how to programmatically change the tabbarItem's image

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I'm developing a shopping cart tab. Originally I just use the default badge value to show how many items in the cart on the bottom tabbar. Now the designer wants to be fancy, he wants to show different image based on how many items in the cart. For example, if there's one, show cartTab-1.png, if 2, show cartTab-2.png...

I tried to change the tabaritem (`UITabBarItem`)'s image but it didn't work for me. Is it feasible? I discussed with my colleague, he said I may have to draw the image on top of the tabbarItem by myself. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

more details:

1. I created the tabItem using InterfaceBuilder, and set the image and title over there
2. I need to support ios4. So I can't use the setSelectedImage...
3. In my case it's a KVO, if the cart count changes, it notifies the method to update the image. not in the initialize step.

does anyone know why `[self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cartxxx.png"]]` doesn't work? When I debug, the property do changed, but the UI remains same

**Update**

the below code works. Thanks everyone!

```
UIImage* cartTabImage = [UIImage imageNamed:cartTabImageName];
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setImage:cartTabImage];
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3.0 version for 2 tabs,

```
self.tabBar.items?[0].image = UIImage(named: "inactive_image_0")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
self.tabBar.items?[0].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "active_image_0")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

self.tabBar.items?[1].image = UIImage(named: "inactive_image_1")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
self.tabBar.items?[1].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "active_image_1")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: .withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) is really helped me.

Answer (score 6):

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem0 = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

[tabBarItem0 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconGray.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem0 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconBlue.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I found was

```
     self.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
```

Comment: `self.tabBarItem` is not necessarily non-null.

Comment: This isn't setting the selectedImage and failed to work properly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int numItems = 0; // count of items in your shopping cart
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cartTab-%d",numItems];

// change your image
[[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:myIndex] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];

// or, if you want to set it when initializing the tabBar
UITabBarItem *item = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:myTitle image:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] tag:someTag];
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did the same thing but the image didn't change. When I debug, the tabBarItem's property is changed to the new image. But for some reason, the UI is not updated. none of the below worked:       
  [self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"]];
  [self.tabBarItem setBadgeValue:@"4"];
  [self.tabBarItem setTitle:@"test"];   
BTW, I did it in the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

This Answer May be Help You

```
  UITabBarItem *i5=[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Profile" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"] tag:5];
```

Comment: thanks
In my case it's a KVO, if the cart count changes, it notifies the method to update the image. not in the initialize step

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)setFinishedSelectedImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:(UIImage *)unselectedImage
```

selectedImage is displayed when the user has selected the tab. unselectedImage is displayed when the user has selected a different tab.

in your `viewDidLoad:` do

```
UIImage *c1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cart1.png"];
UIImage *c2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cart1unselected.png"];
[[self tabBarItem] setFinishedSelectedImage:c1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:c2];
```

Comment: thanks
Since I need to support ios 4, I call the similar code but it didn't work. 
[self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cartxxx.png"]];

I don't call it inside the viewDidLoad neither. In my case it's a KVO, if the cart count changes, it notifies the method to update the image.

Comment: this is an iOS5 method. If you need to support iOS4, you will have to subclass UITabBar and create custom image code... its annoying and extremely long and can get very buggy. There are tutorials around on how to add a  custom image to a UITabBar

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the updated question and other answers, in most cases the `UITabBarItem` needs to be accessed via the `UITabBarController` directly.

It seems that iOS creates a copy of the `UITabBarItem` instance, which explains why updating the `self.tabBarItem` property does not reflect the changes in the user interface:

[image: Two UITabBarItem instances]

My guess is that this happens when the Tab Bar items are created programmatically, instead of by the storyboard, but this is just a guess.

The solution is then, as pointed out, accessing the array of Tab Bar items via the Tab Bar controller. This solution is bad in that it depends on the knowledge of the tab bar item index:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
[tabBarItem setImage:image];
[tabBarItem setSelectedImage:image];
```

Don't forget to update both images for default and selected states.

Answer (score 0):

```
let favorites = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image:UIImage(named: "Screen Shot 2018-12-13 at 11.00.42 AM") , tag: 0)
```