# How to programmatically change the default icon used by a tab bar item?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a `TabBar` item that is a shopping cart outline called "cart". This is a default icon provided by `XCode`. With the tab of a button, I want to change this icon to another default icon provided by `XCode` called "cart.fill"

```
shoppingCartIcon.image = UIImage(named: "cart.fill")
```

**I already tried the above however this didn't work. Is there an easy solution that I am overlooking?**

Comment: see this for help : [how to programmatically change the tabbarItem's image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847483/how-to-programmatically-change-the-tabbaritems-image)

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the customization within this class related to tabbar. Just assign this class TabbarViewController to your UITabbarController in storyboard and customize all images and title accordingly.

```
class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let arrayOfImageNameForUnselectedState = ["home_unselected","info_unselected","puzzle","video","more"]

        let arrayOfImageNameForSelectedState = ["home_selected","info_selected"]

        let titlesArray = ["Home","About Us"]

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        if let count = self.tabBar.items?.count {
            for i in 0...(count-1) {
                let imageNameForSelectedState   = arrayOfImageNameForSelectedState[i]
                let imageNameForUnselectedState = arrayOfImageNameForUnselectedState[i]


                self.tabBar.items?[i].title = titlesArray[i]

                self.tabBar.items?[i].selectedImage = UIImage(named: imageNameForSelectedState )?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                self.tabBar.items?[i].image = UIImage(named: imageNameForUnselectedState )?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            }
        }



        let selectedColor   = UIColor(red: 233.0/255.0, green: 41.0/255.0, blue: 47.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let unselectedColor = UIColor(red: 127.0/255.0, green: 140.0/255.0, blue: 141.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: unselectedColor], for: .normal)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: selectedColor], for: .selected)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```